# How would I find an exe's path just by knowing its name?

Tags: c#

How Would I find another exe's path by knowing its name in .net?

Would I add name to the OS environment variable?
Would the other application have to 'register' itself somewhere else?

I need App A to start-up App B and call some WCF services on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put the path to B in a config setting for application A?

Comment: That would work, would there be a cleaner solution? and by cleaner I mean something that would not require changes to application A if the location for application B changes.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Putting the path in the config setting wouldn't require modifying application A when application B moves.  All you'd have to do is modify the ApplicationA.exe.config file.  No recompile would be necessary.

Comment: @yodaj007: You might want to create an answer with your suggestion and an example.

Comment: Why not make App B a Windows Service and leave it running all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: you cannot know the path simply by knowing the name. An exe can reside anywhere on the file system. There can be multiple instances of it that don't know about each other. Multiple exe files that are completely different can have the same name.

You could take one of several approaches to get round this, depending on the exe you are targetting:

- get the user to browse for the exe using a normal file browse dialog
- search the file system
- see what traces the target exe leaves on the system (filesystem, registry, environmental variables, etc) and use those traces to locate the exe

For either of these options you save the result so you don't have to execute it again when your app is run the next time.

Searching the filesystem could take some time, you are not guaranteed to find the exe (depending upon the user level your app is running as) and you may get false positives, especially if the app is called something dumb like *setup.exe*.

Getting the user to locate the exe the first time you run is possibly the most reliable way of locating it, but then you have to decide what to do if your app runs but the target exe is no longer at the specified location, or the user has chosen the wrong exe.

If you have some control over App B (i.e. it is your product), then you could consider adding some info to a known spot in the registry when App B gets installed, so that App A can locate it easily. You still need to have a plan B though in case the info is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Reference a path to a shortcut of the exe in the config setting, that way if the exe ever moves around the shortcut will still be up-to-date. Try it, make a shortcut to a exe, then cut and paste the exe somewhere else, then double click the shortcut and you'll see it points to the exe's new location thus will not require changes to app A if the location app B changes.

Comment: I have that shortcut feature. It even keeps track of the originating host name!

Answer (score 0):

Really, just make the App B a windows service and start it up when needed.

**UPDATE:**

Another suggestion would be to create a hard link to the AppB's EXE:

```
mklink /H AppB-link.exe path_to_actual_exe
```

Or a symbolic link to whole directory where App B resides:

```
mklink /D virtual_directory path_to_actual_directory
```

Comment: Should have mentioned the application will also have a main window / UI.  It sometimes will need to be controlled without the UI to consume some of its services.